# Problems with \usebackgroundtemplate

Tags: beamer, backgrounds

When I use a figure in `\usebackgroundtemplate` I nothe that the figure in the background does not adjust in my presentation. See the figure below:

[image]

The shadows become white and the figure as background is shifted to the right.
In addition, I would like to eliminate the primary pallete (which is in blue).

I would like the whole image to be in the background, without the white parts.

Below, my code:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table,10pt,c]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}

%Dados da sua apresentação
\author[Aliano, A. F \& Fulano, G. H]{Angelo Aliano Filho \\ Fulano de Tal}
\title[Título resumido]{Título completo}
%\setbeamercovered{highly dynamic} 
\setbeamercovered{transparent=30}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
\institute[Seu inst.]{\textbf{Universidade Tecnológica Federal do Paraná} \\ Departamento de Matemática} 
\date{\today} 
\logo{
\includegraphics[scale=0.08]{logoUTFPR.png}
}

\usebackgroundtemplate{
\tikz\node[opacity=0.7] {
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,
height=\paperheight]
{lousa.jpg}
};}


\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}{Frame 1}{Subtitle 1}
Contents
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}{Frame 1}{Subtitle 1}
\begin{block}{Title}
Content of a block...
\end{block}
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\end{document}
```

Comment: How does it look when you deactivate \usetheme{Warsaw}? If your background image is shifted to the right, it is also shifted downwards, according to the lines appearing. Could you provide for lousa.jpg? And have a look in the documentation whether there is a default offset - either in usebackgroundtemplate or in beamer in general.

Comment: The lousa.jpg can be found in this adress:
https://www.google.com/search?q=lousa&rlz=1C1GCEA_enBR866BR866&sxsrf=ALeKk01IpjcTKCD-dNObLfpvjN4FfhFrGQ:1626961914516&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=2ahUKEwjv0ui36fbxAhXsqpUCHccpB-cQ_AUoAnoECAEQBA&biw=1920&bih=937#imgrc=Dm2KduT-6COJxM

Answer (score 0):

> The shadows become white

beamer shadows are (again) transparent since version v3.60 or newer

> The figure as background is shifted to the right

Tikz by default adds a bit of padding around nodes. You can use the `inner sep` key to adjust this

---

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table,10pt,c]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
%\usepackage{graphicx,color}

%Dados da sua apresentação
\author[Aliano, A. F \& Fulano, G. H]{Angelo Aliano Filho \\ Fulano de Tal}
\title[Título resumido]{Título completo}
%\setbeamercovered{highly dynamic} 
\setbeamercovered{transparent=30}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
\institute[Seu inst.]{\textbf{Universidade Tecnológica Federal do Paraná} \\ Departamento de Matemática} 
\date{\today} 
\logo{
\includegraphics[scale=0.08]{example-image-duck}
}

\usebackgroundtemplate{%
\tikz[inner sep=0pt]\node[opacity=0.7] {%
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,
height=\paperheight]
{example-image-duck}
};}


\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}{Frame 1}{Subtitle 1}
Contents
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}{Frame 1}{Subtitle 1}
\begin{block}{Title}
Content of a block...
\end{block}
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\end{document}
```

[image]